# Google Big Query gives me "there is no data to display"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3oJ5.png) >>> this is image of my query
I have a dataset with over 500000 rows.
I have two columns:

- one is start_station_name column.
- two is member_casualcolumn. it shows two customer types that use the company's bikes.

i need to know the top ten busiest start location for both members and casuals.
it meant that I need start_station_name to appear twice in the output one for top ten locations for members and top ten locations for casuals separately.

my query is correct but I do not know why I get the output "there is no data to display".

I have tried trying with and without "LIMIT".
I do not know what to do please help me.

I have checked temp table too but i am told i need cte because I need two separate columns. i also checked and i have permissions and i have data.

this is my code that has no error:

```
WITH casual_trips AS (
  SELECT start_station_name,
  COUNT(member_casual) AS casual_trip_times
  FROM `cyclisticdataanalysis-402119.2022_Trip_Data.May2022_TripData`
  WHERE member_casual = "casual" 
  GROUP BY start_station_name
  ORDER BY COUNT(member_casual) DESC
  
)

SELECT 
Main.start_station_name,
COUNT(member_casual) AS member_trips,
casual_trips.casual_trip_times AS casual_trip
 FROM `cyclisticdataanalysis-402119.2022_Trip_Data.May2022_TripData`  AS Main
 JOIN casual_trips ON Main.start_station_name=casual_trips.start_station_name
 WHERE member_casual = "%member%"
 GROUP BY Main.start_station_name, casual_trip
 ORDER BY casual_trip DESC,
member_trips DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

For wildcard filters, use **like**. It is highly improbable that you have a member_casual that really is equal to '%member%' and that is most likely why you have no data returned.

```
WITH casual_trips AS (
  SELECT
        start_station_name
      , COUNT(member_casual) AS casual_trip
  FROM `cyclisticdataanalysis-402119.2022_Trip_Data.May2022_TripData`
  WHERE member_casual = 'casual'
  GROUP BY
        start_station_name
  ORDER BY
        COUNT(member_casual) DESC
  )

SELECT
      Main.start_station_name
    , COUNT(member_casual) AS member_trips
    , casual_trips.casual_trip
FROM `cyclisticdataanalysis - 402119.2022 _Trip_Data.May2022_TripData` AS Main
INNER JOIN casual_trips ON Main.start_station_name = casual_trips.start_station_name
WHERE member_casual LIKE '%member%' -- use LIKE here
GROUP BY
      Main.start_station_name
    , casual_trip
ORDER BY
      casual_trip DESC
    , member_trips DESC
```

ps: String literals conventionally use single quotes, identifiers (e.g. column names) use double quotes.

Comment: Pleased I could help, welcome to staxkoverflow. There are site conventions to follow. Eg. There is a checkmark beside the answer I provided. If you click that you tell all users, current and future, that this is a verified answer. You gain a reputation point for doing this too (the answer gets reputation points also)